# IE8 Unexpected Identifier error in compiled JST

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, underscore.js-templating

I have a number of templates compiling using the Grunt JST plugin. I just discovered that this compiled string is causing an "Unexpected Identifier" error in IE8, and I have yet to figure out why.

```
this["JST"]["/tpl/general/pagination.tpl.html"] = function(obj) {obj || (obj = {});var __t, __p = '', __e = _.escape, __j = Array.prototype.join;function print() { __p += __j.call(arguments, '') }with (obj) {
var page = page || 1,
prevPage = 1,
nextPage = 1,
limit = limit || 12,
total = total || limit,
pages = Math.ceil(total/limit),
attributes = attributes || [];

page = parseInt(page);

(page > 1)? prevPage = page - 1: false;
(page < pages)? nextPage = page + 1: false;;__p += '\r\n\r\n'; if(total > limit){ ;__p += '\r\n\t<div class="pagination" '; for(var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i += 1){ print("data-"+attributes[i].name+"='"+attributes[i].value+"' ");} ;__p += '>\r\n\t  <ul>\r\n\t    <li '; if(page == 1){ print("class='disabled'"); };__p += ' ><a href="#" data-page="' +((__t = (prevPage)) == null ? '' : __t) +'">Prev</a></li>\r\n\t    '; for(var i = 1; i <= pages; i+=1){ ;__p += '\r\n\t\t\t<li '; if(i == page){ print("class='active'"); };__p += ' ><a href="#" data-page="' +((__t = (i)) == null ? '' : __t) +'">' +((__t = (i)) == null ? '' : __t) +'</a></li>\r\n\t\t'; } ;__p += '\r\n\t    <li '; if(page == pages){ print("class='disabled'"); };__p += ' ><a href="#" data-page="' +((__t = (nextPage)) == null ? '' : __t) +'">Next</a></li>\r\n\t  </ul>\r\n\t</div>\r\n'; } ;}return __p};
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Edit: Uncompiled template:

```
<%
var page = page || 1,
prevPage = 1,
nextPage = 1,
limit = limit || 12,
total = total || limit,
pages = Math.ceil(total/limit),
attributes = attributes || [];

page = parseInt(page);

(page > 1)? prevPage = page - 1: false;
(page < pages)? nextPage = page + 1: false;
%>

<% if(total > limit){ %>
    <div class="pagination" <% for(var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i += 1){ print("data-"+attributes[i].name+"='"+attributes[i].value+"' ");} %>>
      <ul>
        <li <% if(page == 1){ print("class='disabled'"); }%> ><a href="#" data-page="<%=prevPage%>">Prev</a></li>
        <% for(var i = 1; i <= pages; i+=1){ %>
            <li <% if(i == page){ print("class='active'"); }%> ><a href="#" data-page="<%=i%>"><%=i%></a></li>
        <% } %>
        <li <% if(page == pages){ print("class='disabled'"); }%> ><a href="#" data-page="<%=nextPage%>">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Does `obj` have a trailing comma by any chance?

Comment: I just checked every call to this template, and they all look to be clean of any trailing commas. Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: Could you maybe post the uncompiled template as well?

Comment: Definitely. Just added it to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started getting inconsistent messages from the dev console regarding where the error was actually located. I ended up having to step through the loading process of this page with alert methods to see where exactly it was erroring out. I was unfamiliar with this issue in jQuery, but here is what I was doing:

```
$('head > title').html(NEWTITLE);
```

In IE8 you cannot modify the document title in this way. You instead need to use:

```
document.title = NEWTITLE;
```

Once I put this in place, everything started working. This includes both the site with uncompiled templates and with compiled. It turns out it had nothing to do with JST.